# Recursive Query in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, recursion, common-table-expression

I'm working on a recursive query (using CTE) in MS SQL server (2008 R2). 
I have a structure like:

TABLE SALES

```
PROD_ID     SALE_MONTH      QUANTITY
--------------------------------------
   1        2010-01-01         5     
   1        2010-02-01         6  
   1        2010-03-01         7 

   2        2010-01-01         1
   2        2010-02-01         2
   2        2010-03-01         3

   3        2010-01-01         10
   3        2010-02-01         20
   3        2010-03-01         30
```

Then, we were asked to make a modification an add a table like:
TABLE PROD_REPLACEMENTS

```
ID     OLD_PROD_ID     NEW_PROD_ID 
----------------------------------
1          1                2     
2          2                3
```

The first table, has the Sales of the products per date (really, it's the month that cares). The second one has the replacements: I.E. product 1 has been replaced with product 2, and so.

So, I was asked to make a report that show the sales of the products over the months having in mind the replacements. I.E., if you calculate the sales of the product 2, you will have something like:

PRODUCT 2 SALES:

```
PROD_ID     SALE_MONTH      QUANTITY
--------------------------------------
   2        2010-01-01        (1+5)
   2        2010-02-01        (2+6)
   2        2010-03-01        (3+7)
```

PRODUCT 3 SALES:

```
PROD_ID     SALE_MONTH      QUANTITY
--------------------------------------
   3        2010-01-01      (1+5+10)
   3        2010-02-01      (2+6+20)
   3        2010-03-01      (3+7+30)
```

So, **How do I get this using a recursive query?**

My fisrt aproach:

```
;WITH CTE(SALE_MONTH, PROD_ID, QUANTITY)  AS
(
    SELECT s.SALE_MONTH, s.PROD_ID, CAST( ISNULL(QUANTITY, 0) as NUMERIC) as QUANTITY
    FROM Sales s
    WHERE s.PROD_ID = 2

    UNION ALL

    SELECT CTE.SALE_MONTH, CTE.PROD_ID, CAST((ISNULL(CTE.QUANTITY,0) + ISNULL(s.QUANTITY, 0)) as NUMERIC)  as QUANTITY_TOTAL
    FROM Sales s
    JOIN CTE ON CTE.PROD_ID = s.PROD_ID
    JOIN PROD_REPLACEMENTS pr ON pr.OLD_PROD_ID = CTE.PROD_ID
    WHERE s.PROD_ID pr.NEW_PROD_ID

)
SELECT SALE_MONTH, PROD_ID, QUANTITY
FROM CTE
```

Thanks in advance!!!!

**UPDATE:**

SQL FIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dd607/5

Comment: Unless you can tell us about the table structure there isn't much we can do but guess here. At the very least a sqlfiddle would be a good start. sqlfiddle.com

Comment: OK @SeanLange, i added it here: [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dd607/5](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dd607/5). Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you already answered this yourself?? I would recommend specifying the scale and precision of your numeric though instead of relying on the default.

Comment: @SeanLange why did you say that? I don't answer myself! the Query (CTE) I posted dosen't work as I expect. Did you understand my question? if not, I will remake it! Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. It helps see what is going on and provided an instant way for people to start working on a solution. I am not quite sure what you want for output from the sample provided in your fiddle.

Comment: Do you need to do it recursively? Isn't it just some group by / sum work?

Comment: I thought as recursive becouse you can have X replacments of the product. And if it have a replacement, you have to go and find the sales of that product in the period of time, and SUM to it.
But, i'm open to every solotion. Actually, i'm thinking of a solution using Scalar-valued and Tabled-valued Functions in the BD. 
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you thinking that your single query will produce two different result sets (one for Product 2 and one for Product 3)?   Because that's not possible.